# setFill processing not working in Java

Tags: java, processing

the basis of my code is that if I click on the screen with my mouse, the rectangle will change color. I made the rectangle as a shape called d, and I want to able to change the color without having the redraw the shape.
so :

```
void setup 
{
  d = createShape(); // d is a PShape
  d.beginShape(); 
  fill(100);
  rect(200,200,200,200); 

  d.endShape(CLOSE);
  d.disableStyle()
}

void draw()
{
  shape(d, 300, 250);
    if ( mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 600 && mouseY >=0 && mouseY <= 600 )
   {
       greenC = true;   //a boolean
    }
}

public void mousePressed() 
{
   if ( greenC ) 
   {

     d.disableStyle();
     d.setFill(0);

 }   
}
```

setFill does not work no matter what I do, and I'm very confused as to why.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code does not compile. You're missing variable declarations, you need parentheses `()` after the `setup` function name, and you're missing semicolons. Please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that compiles so we can actually see what's happening.

But your problem is caused by the fact that your shape doesn't actually contain, well, a shape. Your call to `rect()` is completely unrelated to your call to `createShape()`. To create a shape, you need to call `d.vertex()` to add points to your shape.

Please read through [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html):

```
PShape square;  // The PShape object

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  // Creating the PShape as a square. The
  // numeric arguments are similar to rect().
  square = createShape(RECT, 0, 0, 50, 50);
  square.setFill(color(0, 0, 255));
  square.setStroke(false);
}

void draw() {
  shape(square, 25, 25);
}
```